# How I can dynamically subset a ttf font?

Tags: unix, debian, fonts, truetype-fonts, embedded-fonts

Let's say I have a long text:

```
Latebrae agente praefuit imperator nec praefuit ducens insidiarum sunt insidiarum emensis fatorum ubi milites rebus Noricorum viam sorte rebus suis emensis tristissima itaque et vita suis Noricorum erat ulla repente quos sunt spoliari reseratae iumentorum qua fatorum viam apparuit latebrae omnes elegerat Barbatio imperator sub spoliari spoliari eo iumentorum nec sunt sub itaque sunt tristissima vita itineribus latebrae emensis imperio ulla sorte eo et omnes nec permutatione Barbatio praemiis suis ulla ubi praefuit latebrae itineribus spoliari Apodemio latebrae oppigneratos ulla ubi itineribus apparuit ubi cum eo comes certus fatorum elegerat sorte itaque praemiis Apodemio et Noricorum comes latebrae imperator omnes.
```

How I can strip/subset a ttf file, so it would contain only the glyph of the precedent text?

So, the process would be :

- input ttf file and text--> strip --> output generated ttf file

---

***Update***: For those who don't know what [font subsetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Subsetting) is.

Comment: So you're saying you want to create a new font file that contains only the glyphs for the letters used in the text you provide?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 : Yes that's exactly that. This is for a single email, but I don't want to compare each glyph in my text manually.